# Building exaggerated elevation profiles from VRT DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, profile

I have this little challenge, where I need to build an elevation profile from a VRT DEM mosaic of +5000 TIF files. All Z-values should be exaggerated by factor 10 as it's common in road construction.
The profile must be exported to DXF for further processing in AutoCAD.
Currently I'm using the "Profile Tool" plugin to produce the profiles, but there is no option to exaggerate the output.

What's the straight forward method to complete this task in QGIS?

Comment: If you use shaded relief as rendering style, you can manually set the Z-factor. Otherwise, would using raster calculator be a solution for your problem, multiplying the input values by 10?

Comment: Changing Z-factor for rendering doesn't help here, and I guess raster calculator will have a problem with this huge virtual DEM as well.

Comment: What kind of output do get as a profile? A line using vertices with z-values? Can't you multiply the z-value in this case?

Comment: "Profile Tool" can export a 2d-Polyline to DXF, what is exactly what I need. In AutoCAD I have to insert the DXF output as block, so that I can scale Y differently (by 10). Guess there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking beyond QGIS I found the answer directly in GDAL VRT, and it's so simple.
I only need to add <Scale>10.0</Scale> to the VRTRasterBand:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="412502" rasterYSize="323997">
  <SRS dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping="1,2">EPSG:31255</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>-9.75e+04,0.5,0,362000,0,-0.5</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE">YES</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">3107.4699707031</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">1069.9468896567</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">638.24570121125</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT">40.53</MDI>
    </Metadata>
    <Scale>10.0</Scale>   <!-- exaggerate Z-value by factor 10 -->
    <NoDataValue>-999</NoDataValue>
    <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
    <ComplexSource>
    ...
    ...
```